# How to complete OAuth2 authentication on web servers?

Tags: authentication, heroku, discord.py, gspread

Actually I'm working on a Discord Bot which uses Google Sheets as Database using GSpread API, it is hosted on Heroku. So, how to complete authentication ? My Bot is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to head to [Discord Developer Apps](https://discordapp.com/developers/applications) and check off **PUBLIC BOT** at the bottom. This is usually the case 90% of the time with problems like this. 
[image: Gyazo of Discord Link]